# Alternative to && in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

We write our JSPs as XML files (JSPX). Now, for AngularJS expressions such as the argument to `ng-show`, I’d like to use a Boolean conjunction. However, in XML (and truly even in plain HTML), you have to use the XML entity such as `ng-show="itemForm.$dirty &amp;&amp; submitted"` or even `ng-show="addFoodItemForm.$dirty &amp;amp;&amp;amp; submitted"` to be entirely correct.

Now this is ugly. Is there some best practice to avoid that? EL provides an alternative `and` keyword precisely for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was thinking about to wrap a method around.

```
ng-show="AND(itemForm.$dirty, submitted)"


function AND(){ 
 for(var i in arguments){
    if(arguments[i] === false){ // or == false
    //or if(!arguments[i]){
     return false;
    }  
 }
 return true;
};
```

Weird but works for your special case.

Comment: Hmm, yes, a bit ugly. That was the solution I thought of, as well, but I was hoping for something more beautiful.